# Probability Binomial Inter-arrival Time

Tags: poisson-distribution

I think I've solved part a, but would like confirmation, not 100% sure.

For part b, I'm pretty lost. I think it's a poisson distribution because it's modeling wait time? But at the same time, it has frames between arrivals, so I'm not sure.

Let $X_t$ be the number of arrivals after  minutes in a process with arrival rate = $4.2~ \text{min}^{-1}$ . Use a Binomial process with $2$-second frames to model $X_t$ .

(a) Identify the distribution of $X_t$ and compute $(X_t \leq 50)$ using the Central Limit Theorem.

$\delta = 2/60$

$n = t/\delta = 15/.03333 = 30$

$p = \delta\times\lambda = 4.2 \times.0333$

$X\sim \text{Binomial}(n=30, .14)$

$P(X < 50) = \text{ Binomial CDF } (30, .14, 50)$

(b) Identify the distribution of the inter-arrival time (by relating it to frames), then compute the probability that 30 seconds pass before the next arrival.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not Poisson.

Hint: You are modelling arrival in a 2second frame as Bernoulli trials, so the inter arrival time is count of trials until the next success (multiplied by frame length).

What distribution is had by the count of *trials until the next success* in a sequence of Bernoulli trials?